# How message broadcast to subscribers in ConnectableFlux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am new to Spring WebFlux and I found this Chat demo using Spring WebFlux and Websocket in this link:

https://blog.monkey.codes/how-to-build-a-chat-app-using-webflux-websockets-react/

Based on the article, it said:

> The crux of the application is to connect the WebSocketSessions to one
>   another. This is achieved by connecting the incoming message stream of
>   every session to a global publisher. On the flip side, every session
>   subscribes to messages produced by the global publisher.

Reactor Config:

```
    @Bean
    public UnicastProcessor<Event> eventPublisher(){
        return UnicastProcessor.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flux<Event> events(UnicastProcessor<Event> eventPublisher) {
        return eventPublisher
                .replay(25)
                .autoConnect();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping webSocketMapping(UnicastProcessor<Event> eventPublisher, Flux<Event> events) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/websocket/chat", new ChatSocketHandler(eventPublisher, events));
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);

        //Without the order things break :-/
        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setOrder(10);
        return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
    }
```

Chat Socket Handler:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
    WebSocketMessageSubscriber subscriber = new WebSocketMessageSubscriber(eventPublisher);
    session.receive()
            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
            .map(this::toEvent)
            .subscribe(subscriber::onNext, subscriber::onError, subscriber::onComplete);
    return session.send(outputEvents.map(session::textMessage));
}

private static class WebSocketMessageSubscriber {
    private UnicastProcessor<Event> eventPublisher;
    private Optional<Event> lastReceivedEvent = Optional.empty();

    public WebSocketMessageSubscriber(UnicastProcessor<Event> eventPublisher) {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    public void onNext(Event event) {
        lastReceivedEvent = Optional.of(event);
        eventPublisher.onNext(event);
    }

    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        //TODO log error
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onComplete() {
        lastReceivedEvent.ifPresent(event -> eventPublisher.onNext(
                Event.type(USER_LEFT)
                        .withPayload()
                        .user(event.getUser())
                        .build()));
    }

}
```

If one user sends a message then other users can see this because it is broadcasted to all users. But when I read the code I don't understand how the ConnectableFlux (events) send message to all web socket sessions. I also tried to comment the code of UserStats class but it still works normally. Can anyone explain me this?

Answer (score 1):

The code that is sending the message through the Websocket from the server to the browser is:

```
session.send(outputEvents.map(session::textMessage))
```

In other words whenever an event (message) is pushed onto the outputEvents flux it will be sent to the browser through the Websocket linked to the session.

The reason it acts like a broadcast is because every WebSocketMessageSubscriber, that gets created for every new WebSocketSession, publishes everything it receives (from the browser to the server) onto the eventPublisher which makes it visible on the outputEvents Flux.

```
  public void onNext(Event event) {
    lastReceivedEvent = Optional.of(event);
    eventPublisher.onNext(event);
  }
```

The outputEvents Flux is shared amongst all the WebSocketMessageSubscribers and all events received through this flux is sent back over the Websocket to the browser, including events it received from that Websocket.

In the picture below the "Global Message Stream" represents the outputEvents Flux.

[image]